# Spring Boot Security configuring HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

To authorize the requests we override the `configure(HttpSecurity)` method where we mention for accessing API we want which role. But the APIs that we don't mention can be accessible without login. Why is this behaviour?

I didn't write `permitAll()` for the APIs why is this default behaviour?

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

In this code `admin` API can be accessed by admin role, `user` API can be accessed by admin as well as user role, `/` API can be accessed by user role and there is one more API `/student` which I didn't mention and I can access that without login.

Question is how even I didn't write `permitAll()` method for student API.

Answer (score 1):

To protect the API which is not configured in configure method , have to add line `.anyRequest().denyAll()`

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

For every request to be protected without configuring it in configure method

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line: `.antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")` to this: `.anyRequest().hasRole("USER")`.

Answer (score 0):

Only configured URLs are checked. If you doesn't configure an URL, it will not be checked at all.

Therefore, you should add a configuration, that checks all other URLs, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization-filtersecurityinterceptor):

> **11.2. Authorize HttpServletRequest with FilterSecurityInterceptor**
>
> [...]
>
> ```java
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>     http
>         // ...
>         .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize                                1                     
>             .mvcMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()       2  
>             .mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                           3  
>             .mvcMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')") 4  
>             .anyRequest().denyAll()                                              5  
>         );
> }
> ```
>
> 1 There are multiple authorization rules specified.
> Each rule is considered in the order they were declared.
>
> 2 We specified multiple URL patterns that any user can access.
> Specifically, any user can access a request if the URL starts with "/resources/", equals "/signup", or equals "/about".
>
> 3 Any URL that starts with "/admin/" will be restricted to users who have the role "ROLE_ADMIN".
> You will notice that since we are invoking the hasRole method we do not need to specify the "ROLE_" prefix.
>
> 4 Any URL that starts with "/db/" requires the user to have both "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_DBA".
> You will notice that since we are using the hasRole expression we do not need to specify the "ROLE_" prefix.
>
> 5 Any URL that has not already been matched on is denied access.
> This is a good strategy if you do not want to accidentally forget to update your authorization rules.